# set the first radio button is checked in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

How can i get a **easy and clear** way that set the first radio button is checked in Handlebars template. tks

template:

```
<form>
    {{#each this}}
        <input value="{{value}}" />
     {{/each}}
</form>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

expect render:

```
<form>
    <input value="val 1" checked />
    <input value="val 2" />
    <input value="val 3" />
</form>
```

thanks all.

Comment: you want it render from javascript code?

Comment: I thought this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066768/how-to-set-the-selected-item-in-a-radio-button-group-in-handlebars-template , using the block helper.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`{{#each}}` in Handlebars doesn't give you access to the iteration number or anything like that so you can't do it without altering your template and data a little bit:

```
<form>
    {{#each this}}
        <input type="radio" value="{{value}}" {{#if sel}}checked="checked"{{/if}} />
    {{/each}}
</form>
```

and then add `sel` values to your data:

```
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
var html = tmpl([
    { value: 'val 1', sel: true  },
    { value: 'val 2', sel: false },
    { value: 'val 3', sel: false }
]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/27Ywu/

You could of course just set `sel: true` on the first element of your data array:

```
data = [ ... ];
data[0].sel = true;
var html = tmpl(data);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yA5WL/

Alternatively, use jQuery to check the first one after you have the HTML:

```
// Add the HTML to the DOM...
$('form input:first').prop('checked', true); // Or whatever selector matches your HTML
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sPV9D/

---

Newer versions of Handlebars do [give you access to the index](http://handlebarsjs.com/#iteration):

> When looping through items in `each`, you can optionally reference the current loop index via `{{@index}}`
>
> ```
> {{#each array}}
>   {{@index}}: {{this}}
> {{/each}}
> ```
>
> For object iteration, use `{{@key}}` instead:
>
> ```
> {{#each object}}
>   {{@key}}: {{this}}
> {{/each}}
> ```

So, if you're using the latest Handlebars, you can do something special by using the fact that:

1. The first `@index` will be zero.
2. Zero is falsey in a boolean context.

That lets you do this:

```
{{#each this}}
    <input type="radio" value="{{value}}" {{#unless @index}}checked="checked"{{/unless}} />
{{/each}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PHKps/1/

Of course, picking out any other index is harder and leaves you either modifying the input data (as before) or adding some sort of `{{#if_eq}}` custom helper.

Comment: Don't really know when they implemented the feature but you can access the iterator inside `{{#each}}`with `@index` for arrays and `@key` for objects.
http://handlebarsjs.com/#iteration.

Comment: @Maroshii: That stuff was added after 1.0.0-beta6 (which, AFAIK, was the latest when I answered this). I've added an update to account for the the `@index` stuff that was slipped in between the betas and the final 1.0.0, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: this help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`index` will be passed as second argument,

```
<form>
    {{#each people as |value index|}}
        <input value="{{value}}" type="radio" {{#unless index}}checked="checked"{{/unless}}/>
     {{/each}}
</form>
```