# How can I do radio buttons in Ember?

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there possibility  in handlebars to do something like

```
{{input type="radio" checked=model.isAdmin}}Admin 
{{input type="radio" checked=model.isGuest}}Guest
```

property of model, `model.isAdmin` return `true` or `false`.
Because handlebars version is `1.3.0.` answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497754/set-the-first-radio-button-is-checked-in-handlebars-template) doesn't help me!

Comment: you may use [ember-radio-button](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button) addon.

Answer (score 7):

Actually that pretty easy using closure actions:

```
<input type="radio" name="isAdmin" checked=isAdmin onclick={{action (mut isAdmin) true}} />

<input type="radio" name="isAdmin" checked={{not isAdmin}} onclick={{action (mut isAdmin) false}} />
```

Well, if I understood you correctly `isGuest` means *not admin*.
However if its something different, its a very flexible approach, so you probably can do what you want.

However to mention is the `not` helper I'm using. For this you should check out [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers).

[Here](https://ember-twiddle.com/3b98b225ea16be4b5ddf4eef972d786a?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) is a working twiddle with this solution.

Comment: Doesn't `isAdmin` on the first input need to be in double curlies like `checked={{isAdmin}}` ? Unless you are using the `{{input}}` helper.